# Toxic Constructor crashes LoadLibrary( )

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I write software that allows users to load their own DLL that they compile. During the LoadLibrary( ) call a C++ object is instantiated in the DLL. A common error that users make is that they write a "toxic constructor" and do things like use uninitialized pointers, try to access array elements outside the boundaries, etc... This causes a fault at load time (i.e. during LoadLibrary()) and crashes my software, with exceptions that vary depending on what the user did. I have seen other software that can gracefully handle the exception for the same DLL so I know that it can be done, but I've tried try/catch, __try/__except, and even loading the DLL in a secondary Win32 app, which still crashes. The Windows app is MFC (if that helps). Any pointers here?

Comment: Load the DLL into a separate sandbox process which can crash without terminating your process? Then you just need some way for the sandbox to communicate with your main process ...

Comment: I did try something like that with a secondary Win32 app that I spawn with CreateProcess( ) - while my app does not terminate, I still get an error message ("the program PITester.exe has stopped working") that interrupts the loading procedure. I've tried using SetErrorMode( ) to prevent the message without luck.